# laravel 4.2 storing/uploading profilce picture and retrieving from database

Tags: mysql, laravel, web, laravel-routing, laravel-4.2

i m new to laravel 4.2 i'm am developing a web application ..now i want to store a profile picture into database.

this is my controller file code

```
public function profilepicture(){


 $data = Input::hasfile('file');

 DB::table('company')->insert(array('data'=>$data));
 return Redirect::to('/companyreg');
}
```

this is from route file

```
Route::any('/company_profile','CompanyController@profilepicture');
```

this is form view

```
<form method="post"  action="{{url('/company_profile')}}">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submitfile" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: What is the problem that you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all add this to your form tag  `files="true" enctype="multipart/form-data"`

For uploading file take a look at below code :

```
 if (Input::file('file')->isValid()) {

      $destinationPath = 'uploads'; // upload path
      $extension = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
      $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renameing image
      Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path
      // sending back with message
      Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully'); 

      DB::table('company')->insert(array('data'=>$fileName));
      return Redirect::back();
}
else {

  // sending back with error message.
  Session::flash('error', 'uploaded file is not valid');
  return Redirect::back();
}
```

So store image name or base64 encoded string to database and then show that image wherever you want.

Comment: @MohitArya you can use validator rule like `'required|image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,gif,bmp',`

Comment: Thank you so munch .Your answer worked for me .